# C++ Running boost thread from a constructor of a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a class which needs to instantiate a background task as soon as the class itself is instantiated, that runs for the duration of the object's lifetime. Here is the code:

```
// Foo.cpp
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

// Constructor
Foo::Foo() {

  boost::thread thread(&Foo::bar, this)
  // do other stuff
}

// Background method
void Foo::bar() const {
  // do some background stuff forever, sleep, etc
}
```

However once the class is called, the program just terminates immediately -- it says `aborted`. I.e. I have a simple `main()` function that just creates a simple object and return 0, `int main { Foo f; return 0; }` What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct a `Foo` object, the constructor for `Foo` runs. When the constructor finishes, you've got your object. But since the `thread` object is local to the constructor, as the constructor exits, the destructor for the `thread` object runs, and your thread object no longer exists. You need to define a `thread` object in the class, and initialize it in the constructor:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void bar() const;
    std::thread thr;
};

Foo:Foo() : thr(&Foo::bar, this) {
}

Foo::~Foo() {
    thr.join();
}
```

Note the call to `std::thread::join()` in the destructor. Without that, you'll get behavior similar to what you've seen in your own code: when the `Foo` object goes out of scope the thread object's destructor runs. Without the call to `join()` that will throw an exception. In your code that exception is thrown immediately on exiting `Foo`'s constructor; in the revised code (if you leave out the `join()`) it will be thrown when the `Foo` object gets destroyed.

I've used `std::thread` because I'm not familiar with Boost's thread class. My understanding is that they're the same, but I haven't looked carefully enough to write code using Boost here.

Comment: But if bar() does an endless task (in this case I have an endless while loop in there) and then it joins the main thread when the destructor is called, the program never terminates... Maybe the thread can be killed in the destructor somehow

Comment: That's a different question. Yes, you have to have a way to tell the thread that you want it to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is that the `boost::thread` object is destructed at the end of the constructor's function block. If you want the thread object to live for the lifetime of the `Foo` object, simply make the thread a member of the `Foo` class and construct that member in the constructor:

```
class Foo {
    boost::thread theThread;

    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    void bar() const;

    // other stuff
};

Foo::Foo()
    : theThread(&Foo::bar, this)
{
    // do other stuff
}

Foo::~Foo() {
    theThread.join();
}
```